# Woocommerce Dynamic Custom Price not updating in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to update a custom price in checkout via a Woocommerce action hook. I'm storing my dynamic price in Session variable. But when I used session variable in hook functions, it shows up on the checkout page while loading, once completely loaded, the price is set to `0`.

When I pass static value, it stays, whereas the dynamic value goes back to 0 after page completely loaded. AJAX is changing the custom price to 0. Is there any way I can pass dynamic value to hook function?

The function/hook I am using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_product_quantity_discounter', 10, 1 );
function custom_product_quantity_discounter( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through the cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_id  = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $custom_price = $_SESSION["total"];
        $cart_item['data']->set_price($custom_price); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How you make your custom price and how do you pass it into a session variable… Please provide the related code  in your question, updating it, as nobody can really guess that.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have created custom form, thru which I m posting total price.

`$_SESSION['total'] = $_POST['total'];`

Comment: You need to pass that as custom cart item data instead, on add to cart action… So you should provide **in your question** the related location, details and code of that form. Then you should provide the code that process the submitted data from that form too. So please edit your question, adding the related code and explanations.